# How to create a trigger in Oracle that fires before a number is updated and checks to see if that number is authorised?

Tags: oracle

I want my trigger to determined that ApprUserNo = SubmitUserNo or OrgParentNo. Here's my trigger so far :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER cteam_Trigger1
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF ApprUserNo
   ON cteam_ExpenseReport
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 


    ApprOrgNo cteam_Users.UserOrgNo%TYPE;
    SubUserOrgNo cteam_Users.UserOrgNo%TYPE;
    UserOrgParentOrg cteam_OrgUnit.OrgParentNo%TYPE;
    Unauthorized EXCEPTION;
    ErrorMessage VARCHAR2(200);

BEGIN
   SELECT UserOrgNo
     INTO ApprOrgNo
     FROM cteam_Users
     WHERE UserOrgNo = :NEW.ApprUserNo;

    SELECT UserOrgNo 
    INTO SubUserOrgNo
    FROM cteam_Users
    WHERE UserOrgNo = :NEW.SubmitUserNo;

    SELECT DECODE OrgParentNo (UserOrgParentNo,'Null',Raise Unauthorized )
    INTO UserOrgParentNo
    FROM cteam_OrgUnit;
    WHERE UserOrgParentNo = :NEW.OrgParentNo;

    EXCEPTION
    WHEN Unauthorized THEN
     ErrorMessage := 'Unauthorised to update ' ;


END;
```

The trigger is fine up until the SELECT DECODE section.

Comment: And what's that line supposed to do? And what is the error message?

Comment: Check that ApprUserNo = OrgParentNo

Comment: How can an expression in the column list of a `SELECT` check something? That doesn't make sense to me, I'm afraid.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `FROM cteam_OrgUnit;` - the semicolon shouldn't be there.
2. Your DECODE is formatted incorrectly. It might be that you wanted to write:

   ```
   DECODE(OrgParentNo
            UserOrgParentNo, 'Null',
                             Raise Unauthorized)
   ```

   but you can't have an executable statement such as `RAISE UNAUTHORIZED` in a DECODE, which only deals with values. I suggest you rewrite your code as

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER cteam_Trigger1
     BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF ApprUserNo ON cteam_ExpenseReport
     FOR EACH ROW
   DECLARE 
       vUserOrgParentNo  cteam_OrgUnit.OrgParentNo%TYPE;
   BEGIN
     SELECT ou.OrgParentNo 
       INTO vUserOrgParentNo
       FROM cteam_OrgUnit ou
       WHERE ou.OrgParentNo = :NEW.OrgParentNo;

     IF vUserOrgParentNo <> :NEW.ApprUserNo THEN
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Unauthorised to update');
     END IF;
   END;
   ```

I removed the SELECT statements where data was being fetched and never used; likewise, I removed the variables associated with those SELECTs. I replaced the DECODE with a CASE expression because I find a CASE expression is easier to read. I suggest that you prefix variables with an extra character, such as the `v` I added to `vUserOrgParent`, to prevent variable names from conflicting with column names in your tables. This is a potential source of problems which is easier to fix this way than any other. I also took some guesses as to the correct column names in your tables - if they're wrong feel free to fix them up.

Also - triggers cannot return error messages. The only way they can "communicate" with other code is by raising exceptions. I added a call to RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR so the trigger can raise a known exception number.